# How to connect to data source in HUE?

Tags: hadoop, hive, hue

I have been given access to HUE Hive platform by my client. I have also raised all the access requests for the database and all of them are approved also. But I can't see any databases or tables in the Hive interface. Is there any procedure to connect to a database or it should reflect on the Hive interface automatically?

Comment: Without knowing your environment, we cannot answer this. Your HUE administrator needs to modify the `hue.ini` config file to add datasources; nothing is automatic, and "database access requests" don't control what HUE shows.

Comment: Please tell us which platform youa re using and add more details

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.